# Get type of user modifying record - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, attr-accessible

I have in my model:

```
attr_accessible :name, as: :admin
```

And in my active admin initializer:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class BaseController
    with_role :admin
  end
end
```

Is it possible to get the role that is editing the record in the model, to do something like this:

```
validate :thing, if: ->{ modifier == :admin }
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an `attr_accessor` for now:

```
class Service
  attr_accessor :modifier
  attr_accessible ..., :modifier, as: :admin
```

And I send it from the form:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Service do
  form do |f|
    f.input :modifier, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: :admin }
    ...
```

Then I could use it like this:

```
validate :something

def something
  if modifier == 'admin'
     # some code here
```